# How to use md5 hashing in Jboss 6 for JAAS WebAuthentication?

Tags: java, security, jboss, md5, jaas

writing a Java EE 6 application i need some help using the DatabaseServerLoginModule with md5 hashing.

Setup:

**login-config.xml:**

```
 <application-policy name = "app">
      <authentication>
      <login-module code = "org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag = "required">
        <module-option name = "dsJndiName">java:/MySQLDS</module-option>
        <module-option name = "principalsQuery">Select password from user where email_current=?</module-option>
        <module-option name="rolesQuery">
            SELECT r.name, 'Roles' FROM role r, user_2_role ur, user u WHERE
            u.email_current=? AND u.id_user=ur.id_user AND ur.id_role=r.id_role
        </module-option> 
        <module-option name ="hashAlgorithm">md5</module-option>
        <module-option name="hashEncoding">base64</module-option>
        <module-option name="ignorePasswordCase">false</module-option>
        <module-option name="hashStorePassword">false</module-option>
        <module-option name="hashUserPassword">true</module-option>
     </login-module>
     <!-- login-module code="org.jboss.security.ClientLoginModule" flag="required" /-->
     </authentication>
 </application-policy>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Customer Content</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/customer/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>AuthorizedUser</role-name>
        <role-name>customer</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>DIGEST</auth-method>
    <realm-name>The Restricted Zone</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description>The role required to access restricted content </description>
    <role-name>customer</role-name>
</security-role>
```

**The login implementation(the important part):**

```
// login
WebAuthentication pwl = new WebAuthentication();
if (pwl.login(aEmail, aPassword)) {
    return "customer/dashboard?faces-redirect=true";
} else {
    throw new IncorrectCredentialsException();
}
```

**I store the passwords using the following implementation:**

```
final byte[] md5Hash = DigestUtils.md5(newPassword);
md5NewPassword = Hex.encodeHexString(md5Hash);
```

I checked the value that was written into the database with some md5 generators from the internet like http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php

The write all the same.

Using the upon authentication method without md5 hashing at all and with form instead of digest configured works. Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

md5 hash is now recognized as non-safe. It was broken in many ways.

Better use SHA.

Comment: can you give me examples for the implementation?

Comment: @nogamawa - I am not coding on java, so I cannot help you with the code :). But [here](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html) you can see DigestUtils class definition. You can use sha256, sha384 or sha512 according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `MessageDigest` class:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html

Don't use MD5. Use something like SHA-256 instead, and also hash the string iteratively and add salt before the first hash. Hashing functions are not designed for password encryption.

Comment: Does it mean i should not use the hashing functionality of DatabaseServerLoginModule but instead encrypt the password in my code and then pass it to WebAuthentication?

Answer (score 1):

nogamawa ,purpose  of SHA algorithm is similar to MD5, it is one way encryption , ie there is no way to decrypt the message. SHA2 is proven to be much stronger.  Java Cryptographic Extentions (JCE) supports both the algo.
--kiran.kumar

Answer (score 1):

Beyond MD5 vs SHA2 (which is a good idea), It's actually MUCH more important to add a randomly generated salt to each password.  It'd recommend at least 128 bits of randomly generated salt for each password. This prevents Rainbow table attacks (a form of pre-computed password hashes).

You should also iterate your hash algorithm many many many times, feeding it the results of each hash.  Hash algorithms are designed to be FAST, this means an attacker can compute millions or billions of hashes a second with just a cheap personal computer and graphics card.  The recommendation is to do upwards of 25,000 iterations of the hash algorithm putting the output back into the input.  On a modern CPU this takes much less than a second.  If you do this it makes cracking the password that much more computationally difficult.

Comment: Actually, the first rule of crypto is that you should never implement your own crypto unless you want to get hacked. The current gold standard for password hashing seems to be [bcrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/), so I'd go with that.